# Optimise multiple network request

Tags: api, go, server, echo-server

I made a model serving server with Python `Tornado` library and its sole purpose is to accept http request with payload and return result in json. The request can be made with either `application/json` or `multipart/form-data`.

To authenticate and authorise users, I made another server with Golang `echo` library. So all user requests should reach here before reaching my resource server.

Here I have a problem, because my program requires images as input, so users will dispatch their request with `FormData`. When it first hit my Golang server, I need to do the following steps

1. Read the form file.
2. Save it in local disk.
3. Load the file and save it in a byte buffer.
4. Initialise a multipart writer
5. Make a request to my resource server
6. Got result, return to user

I feel like this is redundant as I imagine there is a way to propagate those request directly to my resource server (after auth is done), without having to go through the I/O parts.

My code currently looks like this, at this point authentication is done through middleware. Is there a way to optimise this flow?

```
func (h Handler) ProcessFormData(c echo.Context) error {

    // some validation

    file, err := c.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, response.Exception{
            Code:   errcode.InvalidRequest,
            Detail: "Invalid file uploaded",
            Error:  err,
        })
    }

    filePath, err := fileUtil.SaveNetworkFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
            Code:   errcode.SystemError,
            Detail: "Error when processing file",
            Error:  err,
        })
    }

    f, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
            Code:   errcode.SystemError,
            Detail: "Error when processing file",
            Error:  err,
        })
    }
    defer f.Close()

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
            Code:   errcode.SystemError,
            Detail: "Error when processing file",
            Error:  err,
        })
    }

    var body bytes.Buffer
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(&body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file", fi.Name())
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
            Code:   errcode.SystemError,
            Detail: "Error when processing file",
            Error:  err,
        })
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(part, f); err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
            Code:   errcode.SystemError,
            Detail: "Error when processing file",
            Error:  err,
        })
    }
    writer.Close()

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", fmt.Sprintf("%s", env.ResourceServer), &body)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
            Code:  errcode.APIRequestError,
            Error: err,
        })
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
            Code:   errcode.APIRequestError,
            Detail: "Error when posting request to resource server",
            Error:  err,
        })
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    if res.StatusCode != 200 {
        errorData := &model.PanicResponse{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(data, errorData)
        if err != nil {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
                Code:  errcode.UnmarshalError,
                Error: err,
            })
        }

        return c.JSON(res.StatusCode, errorData)
    }

    result := &model.SuccessResponse{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, result)
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
            Code:  errcode.UnmarshalError,
            Error: err,
        })
    }

    if fileUtil.IsFileExists(filePath) {
        fileUtil.DeleteFile(filePath)
    }

    // track and update usage
    userData := c.Get("USER")
    user := userData.(model.User)
    db.UpdateUsage(h.Db, &user.ID)

    return c.JSON(200, result)
}
```

Comment: Directly copy the form file to the request using `io.Copy(part, file)`.  Delete all code related to variables `f` and `filepath`.

Comment: Steps 1, 2, 3 are not required based on what's shown here. Is there something in the elided code that requires the temporary file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to the comment from @cerise-limón

Essentially, I need just 2 lines

```
f, err := file.Open()
if _, err := io.Copy(part, f); err != nil {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, response.Exception{
        Code:   errcode.SystemError,
        Detail: "Error when processing file",
    })
}
```